# Do a linear regression on a non-linear function in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm, logarithm

I'm not quite sure to understand clearly how non-linear regression can be analysed in R.
I found that I can still do a linear regression with lm by using the log of my functions.
My first function is this one, where β1 is the intercept, β2 is the slope and ε is the error term :

[image]

I think that the following command gives me what I want:

```
result <- lm(log(Y) ~ log(X1), data=dataset)
```

The problem is with the following function:

[image]

I don't know what should I put inside the lm in order to perform a linear regression on my function... Any idea ?

Comment: it would be a little better to write out your equations in a math format, e.g. `Y = beta_0 X_1^beta_1 exp(epsilon)`; more searchable and more accessible that way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following math shows how to transform your equation into a linear regression:

```
Y = b0*exp(b1*X1 + epsilon)
log(Y) = log(b0) + b1*X1 + epsilon
log(Y) = c0 + b1*X1 + epsilon
```

So in R this is just

```r
lm(log(Y) ~ X, data = your_data)
```

You won't get a direct estimate for `b0`, though, just an estimate of `log(b0)`. But you can back-transform the intercept and its confidence intervals by exponentiating them.

```r
b0_est <- exp(coef(fitted_model)["(Intercept)"])
b0_ci  <- exp(confint(fitted_model)["(Intercept)", ])
```

Comment: If this solves your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it (however, you are also welcome to post your own answer, if there are aspects that you can think can be addressed better)